# Equivalent for TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime() on win2k?

Tags: c++, datetime, winapi

One of our developers used this call:

TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime() but unfortunately we cannot keep it as the code must work on Win2K as well.

What alternatives are there for similar functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent, not even with WINE.  It relies on timezone info stored in the registry, retrieved with GetTimeZoneInformation().  Note how the WINE code ends up in find_reg_tz_info().  That info is just missing in Win2k.

You'd have to create your own timezones table.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to including LGPL code in your project, you could grab [that function's implementation from Wine](http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/kernel32/time.c?v=wine-1.1.38#L478).